# Foreign key in django signals

Tags: django, signals, django-signals

i need use node in created method signals, but raise this error

my signals :

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_user_progress(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    specialties = instance.specialties
    section = SectionSpecialties.objects.filter(specialties=specialties)
    section_slice = section.values_list('section_id', flat=True)
    node = Nodes.objects.filter(sections__in=section_slice)
    if created:
        Progress.objects.create(user=instance, node=node)
```

my error :
Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<Nodes: dsdsd - cccc>, <Nodes: chizi nemiyare - cccc>]>": "Progress.node" must be a "Nodes" instance.

my model :

```
class Progress(core_models.TimeStampedModel):
    node = models.ForeignKey(section_model.Nodes, related_name='mentor_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    mentor = models.ForeignKey(mentor_user.MentorUser, related_name='mentor_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='mentor_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Share your models. As the error says, `node` is a *queryset*, so a *collection* of `Node`s.

Comment: node = Nodes.objects.filter(sections__in=section_slice).first() , will get the object instead of queryset, but make sure its the node object you need.